# What is the state of Kerberos support for R2DBC?

Tags: r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I am currently trying to figure out the support for general GSS Authentication but the R2DBC Postgres dependency claims there is no authentication handler for GSS Authentication. I am trying both username and password and Kerberos with Cockroach but it always gives me that GSS Authentication problem. Is there any nice way to support Kerberos (or GSS Authentication-based auth)?

Specifically:

```
Unable to provide AuthenticationHandler capable of handling AuthenticationGSS{}
```

I have tried looking through github pages about Kerberos support but last it was mentioned, it was still in limbo. I have tried seeing if there was anyway I can make it work with my existing setup but to no avail.